# Android giving IOException with 'unable to create directory: /tokens' when using google calendar api

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

Trying to implement the Calendar Quickstart API into Android but when I declare tokens as demonstrated.
`private final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";`

That String is then used in the builder

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
```

But Android returns this error when setting the `DataStoreFactory`

`java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /tokens`

Is there a different method to creating a directory that will work? or must I change the file path of `TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH`?

Comment: t is a known issue in [github](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/java-samples/issues/30).

Answer (score 9):

I used this piece of code.

```
File tokenFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH);
    if (!tokenFolder.exists()) {
        tokenFolder.mkdirs();
    }

    flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(tokenFolder))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
```

And get permissions to external storage in Android manifest file

**EDIT:** The methods specified in Google API documentation for Java doesn't seem to work well for Android. Use this [github project](https://github.com/androidmads/JavaMailwithGmailApi) as a guide for implementing integrating Google APIs into Android applications.