# java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /tokens Google Sheet API

Tags: java, android, google-api, ioexception, create-directory

I finally follow the google sheet quickstart and done the sample application. Now I want to call the API to create a sheet, however, the error shows:

```
    java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /tokens
2020-09-19 01:27:53.967 9027-9097/com.yichuchen.phonecallreminder W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory.<init>(FileDataStoreFactory.java:71)
2020-09-19 01:27:53.967 9027-9097/com.yichuchen.phonecallreminder W/System.err:     at com.yichuchen.phonecallreminder.SheetsQuickstart.getCredentials(SheetsQuickstart.java:58)
```

which is this part of code cannot create directory:

```
 GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
```

I have tried:
[Android giving IOException with 'unable to create directory: /tokens' when using google calendar api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703530/android-giving-ioexception-with-unable-to-create-directory-tokens-when-using)

But shows error:

```
package android.os does not exist
import android.os.Environment;
```

for asking users are added.
[image]

```
permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

and here is my function to call the quickstart.class

```
public void createSheet() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    SheetsQuickstart sheetsQuickstart = new SheetsQuickstart();
    Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, sheetsQuickstart.getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
            .setApplicationName("PhoneCallReminder")
            .build();
        Spreadsheet spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet()
                .setProperties(new SpreadsheetProperties()
                        .setTitle("Test"));
        spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().create(spreadsheet)
                .setFields("spreadsheetId")
                .execute();
        System.out.println("Spreadsheet ID: " + spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetId());
}
```

here is my project and app structure, the `sheetquickstart.java` is outside the app, is that correct? I put `package com.yichuchen.phonecallreminder;` in the first line for my app can call the class.
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: `the latest version, getExternalStorageDirectory() is not to be used anymore,`. No. Just use it. "/token" is no valid path of course an no full path. If you have no permissions for external storage or no write access  then use `getExternalFilesDir("token")`.

Comment: Hi again,I have updated my post, please have a look.  seems that my Sheetsquickstart.java is not in app folder, is in project folder, I cannot call"Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" and cannot use "context" to call getExternalFilesDir("token") method. please help!

Comment: After I copy SheetQuickstart.java into my app folder, i can use "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() "  but get error: java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /storage/emulated/0/tokens

Comment: Yes. But that is because you are on Android 10 i think. Please confirm.

Comment: No , I’m in 11.

Comment: Then make it : `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/tokens`.

Comment: I try it , then get another error said "java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/tokens"

Comment: On Android 11 the Documents directory is writable if you request the usual permissions in manifest and at runtime.

Comment: I have the request permissions in maniferst and at runtime , you can see the update picture. where went wrong?

Comment: I dont know. Then try getExternalFilesDir. Solve that context problem.